# Latest FF Stopped Centering Div

Tags: html, css, firefox

I notice the latest versions of Firefox (including 26.0) stopped centering a div that FF used to center and other browsers continue center (Chrome, Safari, IE, Opera). The div would be centered if the display screen was at least 720px wide, and right truncated for a smaller width, which is the behavior I want.

The following HTML/CSS is a complete example reproducing the no longer centered div for FF:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                width: 720px; 
                margin: 0em auto; 
                padding-bottom: 0em;  
            }

            #outer { 
                min-width: 40.5em; 
                max-width: 48em; 
                border: .1em solid; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <p>Content goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea of the simplest fix to change the FireFox display back to centering the div as previously described?

Comment: If you are using this code in FF .Div center only..?

Comment: It works the same in the latest Firefox for Mac. What are you seeing? Anyhow, kind of a weird setup you have there.

Comment: The exact code you quote works fine in Firefox 26 for me.  Does running Firefox in safe mode (see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode#w_how-to-start-firefox-in-safe-mode for instructions) make things better for you?  If so, chances are one of your extensions is messing with your page...